# Revert back to old Firefox style?

Tags: linux, windows, firefox, browser

Soooo... Firefox updated again (to version 91.0), and it's back to the unnecessarily wide, fat ugly proton tabs it had before:

[image]

Last time they did this, you could revert back to the old style by setting the following options to `false` in `about:config` as shown below:

[image]

However after this most recent update, all these settings are *still* set to `false`, yet my browser is still stuck with this horrible design - has Mozilla now removed your ability to revert back to the old style, or is there now another new setting you have to change?

I remember Chrome did something similar a few years ago when they changed their brwoser tab style - eventually they just completely removed the option to revert back to the old style. I hope Mozilla hasn't done this now as well :(

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I managed to get to the original design:

[image]

It's not *exactly* the same, but I much prefer it!

Here's how I did it:

1. Go into `about:config` and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` (if it isn't already).
2. Then, go to `about:profiles`, find the profile you are currently using and press "Open Folder" for the root directory:
   [image]
3. In the folder you just opened, create a folder called `chrome`.
4. Download/copy both the `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css` files from [here](https://github.com/intrnl/firefox-revert-proton) and place them into the folder you just created. (The files were *just* too big to paste here)
5. Restart firefox and your tabs should look similar to the old design!

As far as I know, there is no better way to do this, but I will update this answer if I find anything.